# Use Chrome to open fb:// links

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, protocol-handler

I have a bunch of fb:// links in the contact list I synched from an old iPhone. I'd like to use Chrome to open these links. Basically I need it to automatically open

fb://profile/XXXXXXXXXX

as

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXXXXXX

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: You will need to make a custom protocol handler. Assuming you are using windows you can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Edit and Search and Replace?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.1.